# Google plugin for Eclipse generates multiple Android client library classes for the same model kinds

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-plugin-eclipse

I'm building a Google App Engine server alongside an Android client using the Google plugin for Eclipse.  I have an unexpected problem when using the automated tool to generate the Android client library for calling the server APIs.

I have 3 model classes on the server-side: `User`, `UserLocation`, `DeviceInfo`.

`User` has a `OneToOne` relationship with `UserLocation`, and a `OneToOne` relationship with `DeviceInfo` (both of these relationships are owned by `User`).

I'm using JPA annotations to model these relationships in the server model classes.

After implementing the model classes, I then use the plugin to "Generate cloud endpoint client library", which automatically adds libraries to my Android client enabling me to perform CRUD operations on the model classes.

This all works great, except that the plugin generates multiple `User`, `UserLocation`, and `DeviceInfo` classes, one for each of the three endpoints.  The problem manifests when I try to add a `User` object to a `DeviceInfo` object, because the `DeviceInfo` object expects a different `User` class than the one I'm trying to add.

I hope that makes sense.

How can I associate a `User` object with a `DeviceInfo` object?

Comment: Does using the fully qualified names of the objects help with disambiguation? You might have to convert from the unacceptable User class to the acceptable one too.

Comment: I tried doing conversion but ran into other problems. I ended up passing the ids of the ambiguous classes to the server rather than the actual instances and letting the server do a db query and attach the object.